# How do I pass a property to Gradle's soapui plugin so that it is available within a project

Tags: gradle, plugins, soapui

In essence, this question is about the correct use of the projectProperties and globalProperties properties in [soapui-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/byte-shifter-ltd/soapui-gradle-plugin).

We have a soapui project that's currently run by Ant and which I'm trying to drive from Gradle. It appears to pass a property on the command line to soapui's test runner like this

```
-Papp.AuthHeaderValue=&quot;${webAPITests.AuthHeaderValue}&quot;"
```

The property is accessed withing the project xml file like this

```
<con:default>${#Project#app.AuthHeaderValue}</con:default>
```

From what I've read this is a project-level property using property expansion. All OK so far. Now, in Gradle, I have this

```
soapui {
    test {
        projectFile = '.\\WebAPITests\\soapUIWebAPITests.xml'
        testSuite = 'SampleTestSuite'
        testCase = 'GetByIdTestCase'
        endpoint = 'http://<server>/<endpoint>'
        printReport = true
        outputFolder = dirResults
        junitReport = true
        settingsFile = '.\\WebAPITests\\Dependencies\\soapUI-4.5.2\\soapui-settings.xml'
        saveAfterRun = false
        testFailIgnore = false
        projectProperties = ["app.AuthHeaderValue=\"${webAPITests.AuthHeaderValue}\""]
    }
}
```

and that doesn't work. I've looked through the plugin's code and that seems to be right but, as it doesn't work, I'm probably wrong or something else is out of place.

If anyone can explain how to pass this property successfully, I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `webAPITests.AuthHeaderValue` the string literal that you want to assign it to project property?

Comment: No, it's a Gradle property but your question has prompted me to check whether those escaped quotes are actually necessary.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes. Removing the escaped quotes seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the escaped quotes. I was being too literal with the Ant properties I was replicating.

```
soapui {
    test {
        ...
        projectProperties = ["app.AuthHeaderValue=${webAPITests.AuthHeaderValue}"]
    }
}
```